# How to check the NTC power derating

Tags: power, resistors, thermistor

Reading an NTC datasheet I have understood the meaning of the power derating plot, which looks like this:

[image]

Meaning that below a certain temperature, the resistance is so high that to allow the 100% of power one should apply a voltage higher than the maximum allowed. 
But I am not sure on how to interpret this data. This graph is taken from a 10k NTC, for which at 0°C is 32554Ω, but according to the plot I can still apply 100% of power, which is 500mW. To achieve that, I should apply more than 120V, where on datasheet they say no more than 50V.

EDIT: The sensor is the [NTCLE100](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf).

Comment: Don't forget about self-heating. At 500 mW this might be significant and completely distort your readings.

Comment: Indeed, mine is more a theoretical curiosity rather than practical approach.

Comment: The heating is a problem in theory too!

Comment: Yes, but I was just saying, in other words, that your point is of course correct, but is facing a different question rather than the one in the OP. Unless the heating problem is related to the reason of low temperature de-rating too. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Meaning that below a certain temperature, the resistance is so high that to allow the 100% of power one should apply a voltage higher than the maximum allowed.

Nope. It means that below a certain temperature the power dissipated must be lower than the maximum or the part could malfunction or be damaged, just as it would were the operating temperature above a certain other temperature.

Comment: So basically is not necessarily known the reason, it is just a precaution/requirement from the manufacturer? The reasons could then be anything, from electrical out of range specifications to physics related to the material.

Comment: Right. It could be something as simple as thermal fracture.